# Couple questions on generating functions

Tags: generating-functions

1. Say I have a generating function $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$. And I want a generating function for $g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n!a_nz^n$ for the same $a_n$. How do I modify $f(z)$?

EDIT: In my case $f(z) = \frac{1}{(1-z)(2-e^z)}$.

2. Are there any results on evaluating coefficients of generating functions modulo primes?

Thanks.

Comment: If $g(z)$ is the ordinary generating function for some series, then $f(z)$ is the exponential generating function for that series. I don't believe that there is some general method you can use to transform one in the other.

Comment: As an example, $f(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt5 }\exp(\frac{1}{2}x)\sinh(\frac{\sqrt 5}{2}x)$ gives $g(x) =  \dfrac{x}{1 - x - x^2}$.

Comment: I have $f(z) = \frac{1}{(1-z)(2-e^z)}$.

Comment: Turns out that there is such a way, and it's called the Borel transform. I believe that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding 1, we have (this is the [Borel transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation)):

$$g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n!a_nz^n$$

$$g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n!a_n \frac{1}{n!}\left(\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^ndt\right)z^n$$

$$g(z) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t}\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (tz)^ndt$$
$$g(z) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t}f(tz)dt$$

So in your case:

$$g(z) = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-t}}{(1-tz)(2-e^{tz})}dt$$

Comment: Thanks. Interesting theoretically, doesn't seem to lead to any manageable result though... :) But I guess there's simply no such result.

Comment: @reuns To be honest, I haven't got the slightest clue. This isn't particularly my strong point (quite new to this).

Comment: Forget about my comment. Note $g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty n! a_n z^n$ converges for one $z \ne 0$ implies  $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ is entire, but for your integral $g(z) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t}f(tz)dt$ to converge (and be holomorphic) on a disk we don't need $f$ to be entire.